# postgresql insert in update

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

```
INSERT INTO analytic_filter_log_device(guest_device_id,query_filter_id,created_time) VALUES (UPDATE guest_device gd
    SET status = false
    FROM(
        SELECT
        gl.guest_device_id AS device_id
        FROM guest_login gl
        JOIN guest_device gd ON gd.id = gl.guest_device_id AND gd.status = TRUE
        JOIN guest_login_ap gla ON gla.guest_login_id = gl.id
        JOIN config_ap ca ON ca.id = gla.ap_id AND ca.company_id = 1
        WHERE ('2018-06-26 00:00:00' IS NULL OR '2018-07-26 23:59:59' IS NULL OR (gla.start_time, gla.end_time) OVERLAPS ('2018-06-26 00:00:00', '2018-07-26 23:59:59')) AND
        get_duration_in_interval(gla.start_time, gla.duration::bigint, '2018-06-26 00:00:00', '2018-07-26 23:59:59') >= 5
        GROUP BY gl.guest_device_id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT gl.id) >= 5
    ) as t1
    WHERE gd.id = t1.device_id
    RETURNING 1,1,now());
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What are you trying to do? Are you may looking for `insert ... on conflict do update`?

Comment: when I run the query I get a syntax error. But all query working individually. Error is  (syntax error at or near "guest_device").

Comment: I don't think you can write update query within insert..that does not make any sense too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a `select` inside a `values` clause like that. You either specify constants using `insert into .. values (1,2,3)` or you use a select query directly as the source for the insert: `insert into ... select ... from`

You can rewrite your query in two ways:

You need to use a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with updated (guest_device_id) as (
  UPDATE guest_device gd
    SET status = false
  FROM(
        SELECT gl.guest_device_id AS device_id
        FROM guest_login gl
          JOIN guest_device gd ON gd.id = gl.guest_device_id AND gd.status = TRUE
          JOIN guest_login_ap gla ON gla.guest_login_id = gl.id
          JOIN config_ap ca ON ca.id = gla.ap_id AND ca.company_id = 1
        WHERE (gla.start_time, gla.end_time) OVERLAPS ('2018-06-26 00:00:00', '2018-07-26 23:59:59')) 
           AND get_duration_in_interval(gla.start_time, gla.duration::bigint, '2018-06-26 00:00:00', '2018-07-26 23:59:59') >= 5
        GROUP BY gl.guest_device_id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT gl.id) >= 5
  ) as t1
  WHERE gd.id = t1.device_id
  RETURNING gd.id
)
INSERT INTO analytic_filter_log_device(guest_device_id,query_filter_id,created_time) 
select guest_device_id, 1, now()
from updated;
```

Alternatively use the `update returning` directly in the `select` query:

```
INSERT INTO analytic_filter_log_device(guest_device_id,query_filter_id,created_time) 
select id, 1, now()
from (
  UPDATE guest_device gd
    SET status = false
  FROM(
        SELECT gl.guest_device_id AS device_id
        FROM guest_login gl
          JOIN guest_device gd ON gd.id = gl.guest_device_id AND gd.status = TRUE
          JOIN guest_login_ap gla ON gla.guest_login_id = gl.id
          JOIN config_ap ca ON ca.id = gla.ap_id AND ca.company_id = 1
        WHERE (gla.start_time, gla.end_time) OVERLAPS ('2018-06-26 00:00:00', '2018-07-26 23:59:59')) 
           AND get_duration_in_interval(gla.start_time, gla.duration::bigint, '2018-06-26 00:00:00', '2018-07-26 23:59:59') >= 5
        GROUP BY gl.guest_device_id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT gl.id) >= 5
  ) as t1
  WHERE gd.id = t1.device_id
  RETURNING gd.id
) t;
```

---

Note that I replaced the hard-coded `returning 1` with `returning gd.id` and removed the useless `'2018-06-26 00:00:00' IS NULL` part (as that is always true)

Comment: Thanks this is useful.